# Mysql database replication (failover solution)

Tags: mysql, replication

Is there anyone know how to do "**mysql database replication**" with **appfog** ? In simple word, just want to use 2 databases sync (2 locations) and set one as master database, and other one as slave. if master server down, instantly slave server should act as master database. Actually databases are hosted on 2 shared servers. because lack of the space provided by appfog. :)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's DBA YOSHINORI MATSUNOBU has developed MHA :

> A primary objective of MHA is automating master failover and slave promotion within short (usually 10-30 seconds) downtime, without suffering from replication consistency problems, without spending money for lots of new servers, without performance penalty, without complexity (easy-to-install), and without changing existing deployments.

The project link : http://code.google.com/p/mysql-master-ha/

Max.